# Can all upper semi-continuous functions be written as the limit of a sequence of non-increasing functions?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am attempting to show that if for each $k,$ function $f_k$ is upper semi-continuous at $x_0,$ then $\inf_k f_k$ is also upper semi-continuous at $x_0$.  It seems like it should be obvious, but perhaps I'm missing a subtlety. But this brought on my question, which to restate the title,

> Can all upper semi-continuous functions be written as the limit of a sequence of non-increasing functions?

I was thinking of something along the lines of letting $g_k(x) = \inf_{1 \leq n \leq k} f_k(x).$  Thanks in advance.